# how to hide ftp connection info

Tags: file, ftp, operating-system, client-server

in windows operating systems we can use ftp commands in file as parameters to ftp.exe as following:

```
ftp -s:filename
```

The parameters filename can contain password, username .... and other obvious commands.

is there alternative way or any other ftp tool can accept encrypted parameter file.(at least encrypted for username and password) to hide connection info from clients.

---

now I am going to generate temp parameter filename (plain text) in code, 
then execute ftp -s:filename
finally delete the filename.

however is there any tool could accept encrypted connection presetting file?

Comment: And how would you decrypt the encrypted password on the client side, without reveiling the key used to decrypt to the client? Please explain your original problem, this one cannot be solved. Can't you give each client his own FTP login?

Comment: I looking if there is any ftp tool may accept command like this:
ftp_tools -s:encrypted_file
so ftp_tool could encrypt/decrypt the file,so end user know nothing about server password